# Phonegap takes too long time to read contact on android 4.3

Tags: android, cordova

I created an app using phonegap to read and list all contact detail

to read contact here is the code

```
var  field=["displayName"];
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="";          // empty search string returns all contacts
    options.multiple=true; 
   var contat=navigator.contacts.find(field, contactSucc, contactError,options);

   function contactSucc(contacts) {
       alert("loading contact");
       var str="";
        for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
            if(contacts[i].displayName)
            str="Name = " +(contacts[i].displayName) + " <br/>";        
            $('#contactId').append(str);
        }


    }
```

This code work almost instant on android 2.3/4.1 (1 second) but it take too long on android 4.3 (25 second)
Most time is take by quering database
Please note:- all device loaded with same amount of contact info (around 1k contact detail)

Is there any workaround.. Or is there anyone who face the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps:

1. Ask for the required information using 'desiredFields' filter.
2. Identify whether you want all contacts or contacts which has at least one contact number
3. Store fetched contacts in sql lite
4. Search new or updated contacts using date time stored when you last time fetched the contacts.